# Regressing Elbow-like Plot

Tags: regression

I have data consisting of light wavelength and some coefficient. The wavelength in the data I have is in steps of 10s and I need the coefficient for a wavelength that is between the values I have (eg. 432.5 nm). Data:

```
wavelen    coeff
380         0.982
390         0.564
400         0.378
...         ...
```

I was thinking of regressing the data I have to find a function that represent the data, but not quite sure what type of function I should choose. I tried exponential and power functions, but the results not accurate for the first few wavelengths due to the coefficient drops extremely fast for earlier wavelengths.

[image]

What would be the best type of regression for this data? I was also thinking of splitting the regression for the first few data points, like a piecewise function. Is this a valid method?

Comment: There are many ways to accomplish this, each with potential benefits and drawbacks. Is there an equation for the phenomenon in this experiment?  If so, fitting a curve of that form would make more physical sense.  Alternatively, you could use simple linear interpolation – it would probably not be the most accurate result but it requires just one assumption (linearity), whereas any other curve (which isn't 'backed' by some physical theory) may (appear to) give better results but would have more implicit assumptions (e.g. the type of the curve and at least one parameter to define it's shape).

Comment: @Chris Can you elaborate more on the ways on accomplishing this? I agree on the matter regarding using functions 'backed' by physics, but I'm afraid I could not find the physical equation for this problem as the data is more based on experiment results. I did consider linear interpolation, however, I would consider it a last resort as it is not as accurate (assuming I found the right regression function).

Comment: Well really it comes down to the two options you've already identified: fit a curve globally or in a piecewise manner.  The latter (interpolation splines) includes many options, linear, cubic (free or clamped boundary), smoothed, loess and so on.  If you really want something that fits the experimental data closely, without concern of 'over fitting' and allowing for a non-monotonic relationship, I'd go for a smoothing or cubic spline. With a bit of tuning, you'll get pretty much identical results with either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Answer

Thought I'd elaborate a little on my comments with a demo of different curves.

The main thing is that short of fitting a curve backed by theory (which we've discussed and I know isn't an option), I don't think there's any one method which is more 'valid' than the others.  With just a single value at each wavelength, using a notion such as error doesn't help, as we can just choose splines so that they pass through the original data points.  You could try to use theory to suggest the curve should be smooth (if that is appropriate) but each of the interpolation methods I demonstrate below provide smooth curves, so this is unlikely to be fruitful as you would need to argue some degree of smoothness and it does not sound like that argument can sensibly be made.

#### Illustration of Interpolation Curves

To illustrate some of the options for interpolating this data, I've taken the first few data points provided in the question and added a few estimated from the provided plot.

Using that data, I fitted a smoothing spline (`smooth.spline`), loess regression (`loess`), cubic spline (`spline`) and polynomial (`lm` with `poly`).

The result can be seen in this plot:

[image: Demonstration of interpolation curves]

I haven't tried to tune any of the methods but you can still see the main differences.  The splines are all quite similar.  Obviously, they have the advantage of passing through the given data points.  You could argue that the 'anchoring' of the spline curves would make interpolating at values close to the original wavelengths more likely to be closer to the 'true' value (but there is no guarantee that would be the case unless some theory can be applied to explain why the curve should be smooth like that).  On the other hand, you could consider the polynomial to give some degree of 'regularisation' and so may postulate that, were many data points to be taken, the true values may 'average out' to a smoother curve of this shape.  Without more data, it really is a case of choosing the assumptions that you wish to make rather than choosing an objectively better way to interpolate this data.

It sounds like gathering more data (repeat readings to average and/or intermediate values) would be the only way to really hone in on a method but I realise that may well not be practicable.

Below is the R code I used to generate the plot, in case it's of use.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(magrittr)
library(tidyr)
theme_set(theme_light())

wavelen <- seq(380, 440, 10)
coeff <- c(0.982, 0.564, 0.378, 0.220, 0.175, 0.160, 0.150)

dat <- data.frame(wavelen = wavelen, coeff = coeff)

# Create a new vector of wavelengths with a finer resolution to view the results
new_wavelen <- seq(380, 440, 1)

# Smoothing spline
smooth_spline <- smooth.spline(dat$wavelen, dat$coeff)
spline_pred <- predict(smooth_spline, new_wavelen)
spline_pred <- as.data.frame(spline_pred)

# Loess Regression
loess_reg <- loess(coeff ~ wavelen, dat)
loess_pred <- predict(loess_reg, new_wavelen)

# Third degree polynomial
poly_mod <- lm(coeff ~ poly(wavelen, 3, raw=TRUE), dat)
poly_pred <- predict(poly_mod, data.frame(wavelen = new_wavelen))

# Cubic spline
cubic_spline <- spline(x = dat$wavelen, y = dat$coeff, method = "fmm", xout = new_wavelen)

# Plot results
plot_dat <- cbind(new_wavelen, spline_pred$y, loess_pred, poly_pred, cubic_spline$y)
colnames(plot_dat) <- c("wavelen", "Smooth", "Loess", "Poly", "Cubic")

plot_dat <- plot_dat %>%
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  pivot_longer(-wavelen, names_to = "Method", values_to = "Coeff")

dat$Method <- "Original_Data" # hacky way to get the original data in the plot and legend.
fig <- ggplot(data = plot_dat, aes(x = wavelen, y = Coeff, colour = Method, linetype = Method)) +
  geom_line()
fig <- fig + geom_point(data = dat, mapping = aes(x = wavelen, y = coeff))
fig <- fig +
  labs(title = "Demo of Different Curve Fitting Methods",
       x = "Wavelength")
fig
```